# Including UTF-8 characters in XML CDATA for Exchange Web Services

Tags: xml, soap, utf-8, exchangewebservices

I am creating calendar entries in Microsoft 365 using EWS. I am making direct http calls and creating my own XML files, no library involved. Within the body of the calendar object (i.e. the notes) I need to include UTF-8 sequences for special characters. I thought I had this working, but now including such encoding generates http error 500 with the message that the data failed schema validation.

Below is an example of the XML that I am creating. Where I've indicated XYZ, assume that those are the 3 bytes xE2, x82, xAC which is the encoding for a Euro character. This fails validation. If I remove those 3 bytes, it works fine.  Note that the XML specifies UTF-8 encoding. I've also set the in the http header "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8".  Any idea how I can specify that EWS should handle UTF-8 characters?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1"/>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToNone" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<SavedItemFolderId>
<t:FolderId Id="AAMkADNjNjA1MTIxLWNlNmItNDBjMS04NWE0LTQ3ZmM0YTFiMTg4MAAuAAAAAADzAjMnWlbcRo51UWjY2+udAQBtGm0AIaIyTp7trMMKSGyiAAAAzNL0AAA="/>
</SavedItemFolderId>
<Items>
<t:CalendarItem>
<t:Subject>Test Euro character</t:Subject>
<t:Body BodyType="Text">
<![CDATA[
This is a Euro character: XYZ
]]>
</t:Body>
<t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
<t:ReminderIsSet>false</t:ReminderIsSet>
<t:Start>2010-08-24T14:30:00Z</t:Start>
<t:End>2010-08-24T15:00:00Z</t:End>
<t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
<t:Location></t:Location>
</t:CalendarItem>
</Items>
</CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enter the actual character.  `CDATA` sections have *character* data, not encoded byte data.  For example, I created the following in Notepad++ and saved the file as UTF-8:

```
<t:Body><![CDATA[This is a Euro character: €]]></t:Body>
```

Hex dump of the file:

[image: hex dump of example]

If you still have trouble, post the code used to build the XML.  If not using a library, it is easy to violate XML standards.  Use a hexdump program and see what is wrong with your file compared to this example.

There's nothing in this data that makes a difference using CDATA, so you could just use:

```
<t:Body>This is a Euro character: €</t:Body>
```

Comment: I think that is what I'm already doing - when I hex dump the xml file, I see exactly what you show in your example. Could I upload a binary of the .xml file somewhere for you to confirm that it's correct?

Comment: @JeffMcKay sure, I can check it. You also said it failed validation. Do you have a schema?  What is the validation error?

Comment: This may be my own problem after all - I was not actually able to reproduce the problem with the single Euro character example.  I've got some code that filters out some problem line drawing characters that was causing the schema validation, and I think that code was also damaging valid UTF-8 sequences.  I need to revisit the whole issue, so I'm closing this out.  Thanks for your help.